# How to introduce a new wildcard in a snakemake pipeline with several rules

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

It has been several times that I face this problem and would like to understand finally: is it possible to introduce a new wildcard in a rule in a snakemake pipeline?

```
workdir: "/path/to/"

(SAMPLES,) =glob_wildcards('/path/to/trimmed/{sample}.trimmed.fastq.gz')

rule all:
    input:
        expand("dup/{sample}.dup.bam", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand("merged/{sample}.merged.bam", sample=SAMPLES)

rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        bwa_index_done = "ref",
        fastq="path/to/trimmed/{sample}.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = "{sample}.bam"
    threads: 10
    shell:
         """/Tools/bwa-0.7.12/bwa mem -t {threads} ref {input.fastq} | /Tools/samtools-1.10/samtools sort -o {output.bam}"""


rule samtools merge:
    input:
        lane1="{sample}_L1.bam",
        lane2="{sample}_L2.bam",
        lane3="{sample}_L3.bam",
        lane4="{sample}_L4.bam"
    output:
        outf = "merged/{sample}.merged.bam"
    threads: 4
    shell:
        """Tools/samtools-1.10/samtools merge -@ {threads} {output.outf} {input.lane1} {input.lane2} {input.lane3} {input.lane4}"""
```

My input files:

```
RD1_1_L1.fastq.gz - RD1_100_L1.fastq.gz
RD1_1_L2.fastq.gz - RD1_100_L2.fastq.gz
RD1_1_L3.fastq.gz - RD1_100_L3.fastq.gz
RD1_1_L4.fastq.gz - RD1_100_L4.fastq.gz
RD2_100_L1.fastq.gz - RD2_200_L1.fastq.gz
RD2_100_L2.fastq.gz - RD2_200_L2.fastq.gz
RD2_100_L3.fastq.gz - RD2_200_L3.fastq.gz
RD2_100_L4.fastq.gz - RD2_200_L4.fastq.gz
```

While trimming it is ok to use it as one single *`sample`*, but when merging I need to specify `L1, L2, L3` and `L4`. So is it possible to introduce a new wildcard somehow specific for a rule?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to introduce a new wildcard somehow specific for a rule?

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that but I think the answer is yes.

Looking at your example, maybe this is what you are trying to do:

```
SAMPLES = ['RD1_1', 'RD2_100', 'RD1_100', 'RD2_200'] 
LANE = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("merged/{sample}.merged.bam", sample= SAMPLES)

rule trim:
    input:
        fastq= "{sample}_{L}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        fastq="trimmed/{sample}_{L}.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        r"""
        trim {input} {output}
        """

rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        fastq="trimmed/{sample}_{L}.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam= "{sample}_{L}.bam"
    shell:
        r"""
        bwa mem {input} {output}
        """

rule samtools merge:
    input:
        expand('{{sample}}_{L}.bam', L= LANE),
    output:
        outf= "merged/{sample}.merged.bam",
    shell:
        r"""
        samtools merge {output} {input}
        """
```

It assumes that all samples have lanes 1 to 4 which is not great but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Some steps like demultiplexing take as input a wildcard, and outputs several files the names of which are different from input wildcard, which I would like to use in the next rule bwa mem for example. Since at the beginning I specify wildcards as (SAMPLES,) =glob_wildcards('/path/to/trimmed/{sample}.trimmed.fastq.gz') ,I do not know how to specify a new wildcard in the next rule.